# How to implement page loader in nativescript-vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can we implement page loader??
Can anybody show me detail code...

```html
<ActivityIndicator :busy="showLogin" :visibility="showLogin ? 'visible' : 'collapse'"  height="50" width="50"/>
```

```js
this.showLogin = this.showLogin==false?true:false;
```

Comment: What you mean by a page loader?

Comment: when interacting with server,it shows loader.

Comment: FYI `?true:false` is redundant, `this.showLogin = this.showLogin==false` is enough, because `(this.showLogin == false)` returns true or false

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show just an [ActivityIndicator](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/activity-indicator/), bind the `busy` attribute to a variable, toggle it whenever you want to show or hide.

Or if you want to block the page entire page completely, try [nativescript-loading-indicator](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-loading-indicator) plugin.